# Check if background execution restriction has been enabled

Tags: android-8.0-oreo

When my application target is below API 26 and it runs in Android Oreo device; Is there any API available for checking if the user has restricted my application's background execution of service and broadcast from the Settings?

Comment: I have not seen any way to detect this, though I am hoping that there is some option somewhere that I just have not encountered.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for looking into this, i could not find it so finally posted it here.